# Integer variables not storing in flatbuffers using python

Tags: python, flatbuffers

I am seeing a strange issue using flatbuffers on python.  I am trying to store a variable value which is integer, however, when I generate the JSON from the resulting .bin file the key / integer value will not be there. 
However, if I simply pass an integer it works fine?

Do I need to do some kind of cast or generate an integer type in the same way as I do for strings?

Here is an example of the code I am running:

```
    varInt = 1

    SomeClass.SomeClassStart(my_builder)
    SomeClass.SomeClassAddMyValue(my_builder, varInt)
    SomeClass.SomeClassAddMyOtherValue(my_builder, 2)
    some_class_buffer = SomeClass.SomeClassEnd(my_builder)
```

which produces json of :

```
   some_class:{
       my_other_value: 2
   }
```

I don't understand why one way would work and one wouldn't? I don't have much experience with python and flatbuffers are completely new to me so not sure if theres some nuance that I'm unaware of?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with this. It turns out that I had to set the builder to have the forceDefaults variable set to true.

```
my_builder.forceDefaults = True
```

Comment: Actually, you don't want that, since that generates binaries that are bigger than necessary. FlatBuffers doesn't store fields that are equal to the default as an optimisation. You don't see those in JSON because, well, they are default. If you want to force seeing them all in JSON, pass `--defaults-json` to `flatc`.

Comment: @Aardappel thanks a lot for this. Very useful! I guess if I had been playing about with values that weren't default then I may have noticed this.